# How to send JWT token to header of redirect URL in Flask?

Tags: python, html, flask, jwt

I'm building a very basic application where in a signup page, user enters his username and pass, and if all checks pass, the username and pass are stored in database and the user is redirected to orders page where he can order items. This orders page does JWT authentication which is why after successful signup, the token has to be passed to the orders page. So the following implementation has been done for signup page:

```
    try:
        cursor.execute(INSERT_NEW_CUSTOMER_QUERY.format(customer_id=cid,
                                                        hashed_passwd=hashed_passwd))
        conn.commit()
    except psycopg2.OperationalError as err:
        print(err)
    except psycopg2.InternalError as err:
        print(err)
    except psycopg2.DataError as err:
        print(err)
    close_connection(conn, cursor)
    payload = {
        'cid': cid,
        'exp': str(datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=30))
    }
    token = None
    try:
        token = jwt.encode(payload, SECRET, algorithm='HS256')
    except jwt.exceptions as err:
        print(err)
    redirect_url = f"/order?token={token}"
    return redirect(redirect_url)
```

The problem is that the token is visible in the URL which is expected from implementation. But I want to send it as header to the orders page.

Please let me know if there's a way to do it here in Flask.

Answer (score -1):

You can return data for authentication, in
Set cookie browser or session !

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I want to stick to JWT only.